# Test a websocket project by postman

Tags: spring-boot, sockets, websocket, spring-websocket

I am learning about websocket by this https://github.com/ali-bouali/spring-boot-websocket-chat-app.
I have this controller class:

```
@MessageMapping("/chat.sendMessage")
@SendTo("/topic/public")
public ChatMessage sendMessage(
        @Payload ChatMessage chatMessage
) {
    return chatMessage;
}

@MessageMapping("/chat.addUser")
@SendTo("/topic/public")
public ChatMessage addUser(
        @Payload ChatMessage chatMessage,
        SimpMessageHeaderAccessor headerAccessor
) {
 
    headerAccessor.getSessionAttributes().put("username", chatMessage.getSender());
    return chatMessage;
}
```

I am trying to test this project by postman. I could connect ws://localhost:8080/chat.
but I do not know how I can test sendMessage() and addUser by postman.
can anybody tell me how I can do this??
I appreciate your help